Observable question related to api result
Recently one interviewer asked me a question about observable. Question was:

'suppose I have two API's API A, B and I want to use API A result in API B parameter inputs. How can I achieve these?'

I was asked for all the possible ways to achieve above scenarios. Can someone provide me some answers?
My answer was I will use rxjs pipe, but they were not satisfied with that answer.

you need to use switchMap, where we switch the observable A, to observable B, its a great operator for sequential API calls, that are dependent on the parent

Pipe to switchMap:
this.http.get(url, options).pipe(
   // use response as parameters for call 2
   switchMap(res => http.post(url2, res, options2))
).subscribe(res => console.log('final res ' + JSON.stringify(res)))

